# Find string nearest to character 250, and split

Tags: ruby, string

So I have a really long string that's a list of TV station call letters. The CRM which I'm putting this into has a character limit of 250 per field. I've created a few fields as a result. I'd like to split a string to 250 characters, then I'd like to find the last occurrence of ", "

```
str = "WPXN, KPXN, WCPX, WPPX, KPXD, KKPX, WBPX, WPXA, WWPX, WPXW, KPXB, WPXD, KPPX, WXPX, KPXM, WPXM, WVPX, KPXC, WOPX, KSPX, KPXG, KPXG-LD, WINP, WIPX, WRPX, WFPX, WNPX, WHPX, KPXE, KUPX, WPXE, KPXL, WPXP, WZPX, WPXH, WPXV, KOPX, WGPX, WPXC, WPXJ-LP, WPXX, WPXJ, WPXQ, WPXL, WQPX, WYPX, WPXK, KTPX, WUPX, WLPX, WPXR, KFPX, KPXO, WSPX, KPXR, WEPX, WTPX"

str[0...250]
# returns "WPXN, KPXN, WCPX, WPPX, KPXD, KKPX, WBPX, WPXA, WWPX, WPXW, KPXB, WPXD, KPPX, WXPX, KPXM, WPXM, WVPX, KPXC, WOPX, KSPX, KPXG, KPXG-LD, WINP, WIPX, WRPX, WFPX, WNPX, WHPX, KPXE, KUPX, WPXE, KPXL, WPXP, WZPX, WPXH, WPXV, KOPX, WGPX, WPXC, WPXJ-LP, WPXX"

# leftover_string = do something here
# returns ", WPXX"

appropriate_length_string = str[0...250].chomp(leftover_string)
longer_string = str[251..-1]
longer_string.insert(leftover_string + ", ",0)
# recusrively run until all strings are in an array or something.
```

Make sense? I don't know how to do the "do something here" part.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). How are you going to present the records to a user? Typically we'd use an array to populate a drop-down or list, not a string.

Comment: This isn't for a user... it's for entering data into another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression ([`String#[regexp]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)):

```
str[0,250][/,[^,]*$/]
# => ", WPXX"
```

using [`String#rindex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-rindex):

```
s = str[0,250]
s[s.rindex(',')..-1]
# => ", WPXX"
```

Alternative that use [`String#rpartition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition) suggested by Cary Swoveland:

```
str[0,250].rpartition(',')[1..2].join
# => ", WPXX"
```

Comment: Also `str[0...250].rpartition(',').first`

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Do you mean `str[0...250].rpartition(',')[1,2].join`? I added this to the answer. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I misread the question.  I thought the substring was wanted.  I also didn't read your answer very carefully.  Shame!

Comment: and if we make use of string's structure, `str.scan(/, \w{4}/)[(250-11)/6] # => ", WPXX"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to loop or recurse. Here's a quick looping example that most probably could be improved.

```
str = "WPXN, KPXN, WCPX, WPPX, KPXD, KKPX, WBPX, WPXA, WWPX, WPXW, KPXB, WPXD, KPPX, WXPX, KPXM, WPXM, WVPX, KPXC, WOPX, KSPX, KPXG, KPXG-LD, WINP, WIPX, WRPX, WFPX, WNPX, WHPX, KPXE, KUPX, WPXE, KPXL, WPXP, WZPX, WPXH, WPXV, KOPX, WGPX, WPXC, WPXJ-LP, WPXX, WPXJ, WPXQ, WPXL, WQPX, WYPX, WPXK, KTPX, WUPX, WLPX, WPXR, KFPX, KPXO, WSPX, KPXR, WEPX, WTPX"

chunk_size = 30
pos1 = 0
pos2 = pos1 + chunk_size
result = []

while pos2 < str.size do
  pos2 = str[pos1..pos2].rindex(",") + pos1
  result << str[pos1..pos2].strip
  pos1 = pos2 + 1
  pos2 += chunk_size
  result << str[pos1..pos2].strip if pos2 > str.size
end

p result
```